# Auto mount sd-card at startup of Xubuntu 16.04 (fstab) not working

Tags: 16.04, mount, xubuntu, sd-card

### Preliminary Note

On Xubuntu 14.04 I had the below config in fstab that worked wonderfully:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /sdbackup vfat comment=x-gvfs-show,users,uid=1000,nofail,nobootwait,auto 0 0
```

### Issue

But the above config doesn't work on Xubuntu 16.04 anymore. It fails to mount the sdcard for I get the message: *"error: sdcard is missing!"*, so that my backup bash cannot find the mountpoint. My backup bash is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
if mountpoint -q /sdbackup
then
echo "sdcard found: start syncing"
rsync -av --delete /var/lib/automysqlbackup /sdbackup
else
echo "error: sdcard is missing!"
fi
```

### Help

Could you please tell me what changed in 16.04 and why the mounting is not working anymore. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What is the `blkid` of the sd-card?  You could run `sudo blkid` and record the UUID of the sd-card.  Then change `/dev/mmcblk0p1` of the `fstab` to `UUID=` then the UUID of the sd-card.  The reason I do it is that the `/dev/name` can change

Comment: oh I never thought about using the uuid. Thanks so much for your input, I will try it out and post my findings.

Comment: Terrance, what happens when my client decided to switch the sd card? I was thinking that if I attach a fixed UUID to the mounting point, the system only will mount the sd card with this particular UUID, so with a different sd card the system might not want to mount it?

Comment: Either way, with the `/dev/whatever` name it is or the UUID, it would have to be updated in the `fstab` file.  However, leaving USB drives in, or leaving another sd-card in can cause the `/dev/name` to change.  Look at what the `/dev/name` designations are for what you currently have when you run the `sudo blkid` command.